# filters in where statement not working for oracle query

Tags: oracle, filter, where-clause

In my oracle query:

```
Select
d.LVL_NAME
,d.SCHEDULE_DESC
,d.SCHEDULE_TYPE
,s.DUE_DTTM
,s.WARNING_DTTM
,s.DELINQUENT_DTTM
,d.EST_WORK_DURATION
,d.EST_WORK_DURATION_UNIT
,l.ENTITY_GRP
from smsdw.TW_SCHEDULE_DEF d
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
smsdw.TW_ENTITY_SCHED s on
d.LVL_NAME = s.ENTITY
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdw.TW_ENTITY_GRP_LST l on
s.ENTITY = l.ENTITY

WHERE l.ENTITY_GRP NOT LIKE '%Wet%' 
  AND l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Implant%' or l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Thermal%' 
  and s.DUE_DTTM between sysdate and sysdate +30 ;
```

I cannot figure out how to get the "NOT LIKE WET" and the "sysdate" filter to work in my WHERE statement.
Any ides?
I have inserted images of my results.
[image: l.ENTITY_GRP NOT LIKE '%Wet%']
[image: s.DUE_DTTM between sysdate and sysdate +30]

I have tried many different ways that I have found from googling, but I still get the same results listed in my problem.

Comment: you likely need to wrap your l.entity_GRP in ()'s `AND (l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Implant%' or l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Thermal%' )`

Comment: thank you. looks like this worked for both filter issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ()'s around your OR. assuming all ANDS are meant to be applied to whole set.

```
WHERE l.ENTITY_GRP NOT LIKE '%Wet%' 
  AND (l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Implant%' or l.ENTITY_GRP LIKE 'Thermal%')
  AND s.DUE_DTTM between sysdate and sysdate +30 ;
```

What's happening is the OR says bring back any group like thermal regardless if it's not like wet and not within the due_dttm date range.

Comment: thank you. looks like this worked for both filter issues. I appreciate the explanation as well.

Comment: Ands are additive.  or's are Branches  ()'s provide control over the branches.  So now it reads it can't be 'Wet' it must be in implant or thermal and it has to be between date range.  Before it was (not like wet and implant).  OR (like thermal and between date range.)